# Change defval to Daily Market Open Price

Tags: pine-script

With the following code:

```
study("Percent Lines", overlay=true)

initialValue = input(type=source, defval=open)

line15  = plot(initialValue * 1.15, color = green)
line20 = plot(initialValue * 1.20, color = green)
line25 = plot(initialValue * 1.25, color = green)
line30 = plot(initialValue * 1.30, color = green)
```

How would I change defval to the market open price at 9:30am (for US markets) to give me a horizontal line on the chart, and have the line change on each new day correlated to the market open price on that day?

Been trying for hours now over several days but as a novice (this is my first coding outside of spreadsheet formulas) it's got me stumped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out!

This code does what I want,

```
study("Percent Lines", overlay=true)

markethours = "0930-1600", dailyopen = "0930-0931"

openprice = time("1", dailyopen) ? open : time("1", markethours) ? openprice[1] : na


line15  = plot(openprice * 1.15, color = green)
line20 = plot(openprice * 1.20, color = green)
line25 = plot(openprice * 1.25, color = green)
line30 = plot(openprice * 1.30, color = green)
```

I'm going to try and modify it so I only see the indicator during market hours (i.e. not during pre or post market), will update if I get that part working.

Hope it helps someone, and it feels good to contribute a tiny part to the community.